# AWS Lambda function: Timeout after 900 secs

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

I am invoking an AWS Lambda function locally using `aws-sam cli` command and I have set the `Timeout property to 900 seconds` but still it shows `function timeout error`. However, when I was invoking this function in `lambda handler` in AWS Console these 900 seconds were enough for the inferencing.

Please help me figure out a solution for this issue and what is the maximum limit I can go for Timeout?

[image: Error]

Comment: 900s is max. Seems lambda is wrong tool for your use-case.

Comment: Nothing we can do. 900s is the max duration. You would need to debug and profile your code to see what takes too long and why, etc.

Comment: I would recommend training your models with [Sagemaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/). Lambda is not the right tool for this.

Comment: Yes, I had trained the model on sagemaker. I'm using lambda for the deployment purpose only. Also, my model only provide inferencing on the GPU, so is there any option for including GPU to lambda function?

Comment: No, use EC2 instances instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions (as at July 2021) can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes (which is 900 seconds).

Some people do 'interesting' things like:

- Call another Lambda function to continue the work, or
- Use [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) to orchestrate *multiple* AWS Lambda functions

However, it would appear that your use-case is Machine Learning, which does not like to have operations stopped in the middle of processing. Therefore, **AWS Lambda is not suitable for your use-case**.

Instead, I would recommend using **Amazon EC2 spot instances**, which will likely be lower-cost for your use-case. While spot instances might occasionally be terminated, your use-case can probably handle the need to re-run some processing if this happens.